# In a proof of the Fourier inversion theorem

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

The following is the Fourier inversion theorem on Schwartz space and the beginning of its proof in Hunter's *Applied Analysis* (p.305):

[image]

> Would anybody elaborate how the one dimensional case could imply the general case? (Suppose this proposition is true for $n=1$, how can one get the higher dimension case?)

---

Here are the related definitions for $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{F}^*$:
[image]
[image]

Comment: @AlexR. I don't see how that has anything much to the question. How does showing the one-dimensional FT is continuous show the same for $\Bbb R^n$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We consider the case $n=2$; the general case is the same except for notation.
Define two partial Fourier transform operators $G_1$ and $G_2$ by $$G_1f(s,y)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int f(x,y)e^{-isx}\,dx$$and
$$G_2f(x,t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int f(x,y)e^{-ity}\,dy.$$Define $G_1^*$ and $G_2^*$ similarly, without the minus signs in the exponent.

The one-dimensional case shows that $G_j^{-1}=G_j^*$. Fubini's Theorem shows that $\mathcal F=G_1G_2$ and $\mathcal F^*=G_2^*G_1^*$. Hence $\mathcal F$ is invertible, with $$\mathcal F^{-1}=G_2^{-1}G_1^{-1}=G_2^*G_1^*=\mathcal F^*.$$